# Zip a directory so that it returns the acutal directory when upacked

Tags: python, directory, zip

I have a script that zips a directory using the following code:

```
def zipdir(path, ziph):
    # ziph is zipfile handle
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            ziph.write(os.path.join(root, file),arcname=file)
zip = zipfile.ZipFile('/path/to/directory.zip','w')
zipdir('/path/to/directory/',zip)
```

When I unzip this I end up with the contents of the directory as opposed to the original directory containing the files. How should I change this so the unzipping returns the original directory with the files still inside?

ie.) unzip --> /unzip/location/directory/file_from_directory

as opposed to

unzip --> /unzip/location/file_from_directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `file` as arcname, but you want the file plus the deepest directory in the path:

```
        for file in files:
            deepest_dir = os.path.split(root)[-1]
            fname = os.path.join(deepest_dir, file)
            ziph.write(os.path.join(root, file), arcname=fname)
```

Comment: The problem with eliminating the arcname statement is that it includes the higher directories as well. The script I'm writing converts tar files to zip files and the tar files used as an input are found in directories like /transform/gwarner/test/file.tgz. If I run this without the arcname statement the .zip file contains everything up to highest level directory under root. I just want the lowest directory included.

Comment: You mean /test/file.tgz? In that case just split the path string on '/' (`os.path.sep` if you want to keep it generic), keep the last two things (deepest directory and file name) and join them with '/'.

Comment: Sorry I'm a little confused. Are you talking about in the `for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):` line?

Comment: See my update response, is that what you're trying to do?